# How to change default application underground and open its file directly android

Tags: android, file, default

I have application with button which can open, preview PDF file directly using another application NOT using Adobe Acrobat (using hp EPrint app, its package name : com.hp.android.print). How can I change its default application without display launcher, and directly open using hp Eprint app (its package name : com.hp.android.print) ?

[image]

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact intent "hp EPrint" is looking for, you can use it by making an explicit intent. (A good way to do so is also to look at your device logcat, when the app opens on choosing it through a menu)

If, however, you are using an implicit intent, then you should always let the user choose which PDF reader he wants to use, until he sets one as "Default"

Comment: already decompiled for its apk, and how to fill its variable URI? could I do this from my application ?

Comment: URI is suaully the path (it can be the local path like file:///, or network path like http:// ), of the file you want to open. Just fill it up in the intent and make an explicit intent